# Parsing a log file - find lines which contain a value from array of strings

Tags: powershell

this is probably really simple... but how do I check which lines of a log/config file **contain** any of the strings from a string array?

Example of file (I want lines 3 and 5)

```
[Privilege Rights]
SeSystemtimePrivilege = *S-1-5-19,*S-1-5-21-2262136377-125853592-2400401627-1119,*S-1-5-32-544
SeDenyNetworkLogonRight = Guest
SeCreatePagefilePrivilege = *S-1-5-32-544
SeDenyServiceLogonRight = *S-1-5-21-2262136377-125853592-2400401627-1119
SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege = *S-1-5-32-544
SeAuditPrivilege = *S-1-5-19,*S-1-5-20
```

Script I am using:

```
$SeRightsArray = @(
'SeDenyNetworkLogonRight',
'SeDenyBatchLogonRight',
'SeDenyServiceLogonRight',
'SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight',
'SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight')

 $LocalPolicyExport = gc "C:\local-security-policy.inf"

Foreach($Line in $LocalPolicyExport){
    if ($Line -match $SeRightsArray ){
        write-host "FOUND - $line" 
    }
}
```

Normally I would use something like -contains or -in, but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gc "C:\local-security-policy.inf" | select-string $seRightsArray`. No need for a loop

```
PS C:\> gc .\test.txt|select-string $SeRightsArray

SeDenyNetworkLogonRight = Guest
SeDenyServiceLogonRight = *S-1-5-21-2262136377-125853592-2400401627-1119
```